# Why is a modular form an automorphic form?

Tags: automorphic-forms

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form) a modular form is a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb H \to \mathbb C$ satisfying quasi-invariance under the action of $SL(2, \mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb H$ and a growth condition.

Also, according to Wikipedia an automorphic form is a "nice" function on a group $G$ to $\mathbb C$ satisfying invariance under a discrete subgroup $\Gamma \subset G$ and a growth condition.

I don't see how a modular form is an automorphic form. $SL(2, \mathbb Z)$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb H$, right?

Edit: I don't even see how $\mathbb H$ is a group. It is not a group under normal $+$ or $\times$.

Comment: You might find this reference helpful https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/adelic_mod_forms.pdf

Comment: @EricTowers No I didn't. Because in modular form definition, the function is defined on $\mathbb H$ not $\operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{H})$.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't even see how $\mathbb H$ is a group.

Comment: For $f \in S_k(SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$, $\Bbb{H} = GL_2(\Bbb{R}) / \Bbb{R}^* SO_2(\Bbb{R})$ then $F(-g)=F(g) = \det(g)^{k/2}(ci+d)^{-k} f(g.i), g = \pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$  is an automorphic form $\in L^2(GL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \setminus GL_2(\Bbb{R}))$. To obtain an automorphic form $\in L^2(GL_2(\Bbb{Q}) \setminus GL_2(\Bbb{A_Q}))$ for $g \in  GL_2(\Bbb{A_Q})$ 
 take $y \in GL_2(\Bbb{Q})$ and a sequence $a_n \in GL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ such that $ ya_n g_\infty \to g$ and 
 set $F(g)=F(y^{-1} g_\infty)$.

Comment: The [automorphic representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuspidal_representation) is to make $GL_2(\Bbb{A_Q})$ act by right translation on the sub Hilbert space of $L_2(GL_2(\Bbb{Q})\setminus GL_2(\Bbb{A_Q}))$ generated by the right translates of $F$. The next step is to make the convolution algebra $u \mapsto u(g) \pi(g)dg$ act on $V$, this convolution algebra decomposes in a product over $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $f:\mathbb H\to\mathbb C$ and $g:G\to\mathbb C$ in the two definitions do not correspond directly, because $\mathbb H$ is not a group.

But dig into the [modular forms Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form) and there is an equivalent definition, **Definition in terms of lattices**.

A lattice on the complex plane can be defined by a pair of complex numbers $u=u_1+u_2 i, v=v_1+v_2i$ with $u_1v_2-v_1u_2> 0.$ This can be seen as a matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}u_1&v_1\\u_2&v_2\end{pmatrix}\in GL(2,\mathbb R),\det A>0$$ But if $B\in SL_2(2,\mathbb Z)$ we get that $BA$ defines the same lattice as $A$ does, and $\det BA=\det A>0.$

This means we can take $G=\{A\in GL(2,\mathbb R)\mid \det A>0\}$ and $\Gamma=SL_2(2,\mathbb Z)$, and a function $F$ from the set of lattices to $\mathbb C$ can be seen as a function $F':G\to\mathbb C$ with the property that  $F'(\gamma g)=F'(g)$ for all $\gamma\in \Gamma, g\in G.$

So, a modular form can be seen as a map $F'$ of a group $G$ to $\mathbb C$ where the distcrete sub group $\Gamma\subset G$ acts invariantly.

Now, the only question is if this $F'$ can be seen to satisfy the requirements of an automorphic form, based on the modular form requirement from which it arises.

I won't go into those details, but suffice to say, the reason studying modular forms is a case of studying automorphic forms in not based on a simple read of the the more elementary definitions of the two.